# Why I am getting "Cannot load a resource from a ResourceScope that has been disposed" error while editing an item in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, microsoft-lists

I tried to edit an item in SharePoint list from information panel and it gave me below error

[image]

Any idea why this error is generated?

**Note : My site has enough available storage and all stage recycle bins are also empty.**

Comment: Can you confirm this - are you editing the item properties from "Open in details pane ( i )" OR are you using any customized list form?

Comment: it is default information panel. Just clicked on Title column and it opens the information panel and then editing the item from there.

Comment: Please see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-load-a-resource-from-a-resourcescope-that/fa8dd382-4a71-4dfe-892c-7cd27f6d1c8d
and: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-load-a-resource-from-a-resourcescope-that/83238d9c-3c2b-444d-97a2-c0c37ae3c084

And see if the resolutions there apply to you.

Comment: Try clearing the cache and cookies of your browser, and then try editing the item again. Or try opening the site in a different browser or on a different machine.